# Using C++ assert to check if a value exists

Tags: c++, assert

How can I use c++ assert to check if a value is found in an array? I know I could use a simple for loop but I am supposed to use assert for my project.

**Function signature:**

```
template <class K, class V>
K& Map<K, V>::operator[](const V &value) const //Assert the argument is found 
//in the Values array and then return the key with the given value 
{
}
```

**Update:**

Is this code correct? I am not sure since it does not use assert to check if the value is found in an array.

```
template <class K, class V>
K& Map<K, V>::operator [] (const V &value) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (A2[i] == value)
            return A1[i];
    }

    assert(false);
}
```

Comment: We need to know what `Map` is.

Comment: Also, `operator[]` cannot be `const` if the `Map` works anything like `std::map`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This `operator[]` will assert the key already exists, it is a precondition that the argument will be found. So it will not insert new elements and is not intended to behave like `std::map`.

Comment: using assert is no alternative to using a loop. You can do it with or without assert and with or without a (explicit) loop

Comment: *"I know I could use a simple for loop but I am supposed to use assert for my project."* `assert` is not a replacement for `for` here. You have to *some how* determine if `value` is in your map, then you can `assert` that condition.

Comment: please show your code that uses a loop. There is a misunderstanding somewhere, but currently its not clear what that is

Comment: I have added a piece of my code that uses a loop. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: " it does not use assert to check if the value is found in an array." why do you think that? It does use `assert` and it does check whether the value is found in the array.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks for the help. I thought I have to use assert inside of my for loop.

Comment: you can only know if you found the value after the loop.

Comment: Are you meant to be looking up the *value* to find the *key*? It is usually the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this code correct?

`assert` is "disabled" when `NDEBUG` is set. else `std::abort` would be called (after a diagnostic).

So, if code reaches that `assert`,

if `NDEBUG` is defined, your program reaches end of function returning non-void type, so it is undefined behavior.

If set, program is well defined and `abort`.

`throw`ing exception might be more appropriated.